# Javascript string replacement not taking effect until length fulfilled instead of instantanoeus

Tags: javascript

I have an `html element` that inputs a phone number. It has both an `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` events that do this:

```
document.getElementById("phone").value = document.getElementById("phone").value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
```

Now, when I use this it works fine however it only makes the changes once the user has typed 10 numbers. **What I'm looking for is instantaneous updates that show the formatting while the user is typing**.

I don't know how to modify the code to make it work as so.

Comment: Not sure but couldn't it be because of the `{3}` + `{3}` + `{4}` ?

Comment: please provide your onkeydown and onkeyup functions and the html to better debug

Comment: What about just using a placeholder attribute?

Comment: @Daenu That's what I need help on. To modify this.

Comment: It is not recommended to change user input as it is entered as this could cause some confusion. However if you really want to do that you will need to change your regex (`/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/`) because right now it won't trigger unless you have 10 digits.

Comment: @Technoh That's what I need help on. Modifying this.

Comment: Your regex won't match, and hence won't do anything, until you have ten digits.  This regex looks like it belongs in a .blur handler (or .input handler), not keyup/keydown.

Comment: Try mix in some `if...else` conditions that considers the length of the input. Say if `value.length > 6` start doing something, then else if `value.length > 3` start doing something, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this regular expresion to update value on-the-go:

```
document.getElementById("phone").value = document.getElementById("phone").value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
```

it will at once add dashes and fill up the gaps with numbers while typing